# How to draw an image with android.graphics?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image, graphics

I'm not very familiar with the android classes yet, but I pretend to develop a game using just the Eclipse and the ADT Plugin. I've discovered that Android has [android.graphics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html) with a lot of classes, and I would like to see a basic android activity code to just draw a resource image on the screen so that I can see the path that I should tread.

Comment: go to the APIDemos and check FingerPaint sample under the Graphics content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to make an Android game you could consider using a GameView
and you could render the image to screen by drawing it to a surface.

[Here's a youtube tutorial as well as example activity code](http://en.edu4android.com/tutorials/game/drawing-an-image-using-surface-view.jsp)